How to modify the value of smallest width in Android system source code
I have a source code for the Android system and I would like to make modifications to it so that the smallest width value of drawing under developer options can be customized
Most of the answers I find online are related to adapting to different screens through smallest width, but what I want is to modify the smallest width instead of adapting to the screen based on it
and i know i can change smallest width  value in developer option simply.
like:(size:800*1280)
adb shell wm density 180

smallest width maybe change to 650~658 randomly.
but i don't want to use this method.
my requirement is that the initial value of the Smallest width I want for the Android system

What have you tried so far?

?  I have been searching for relevant answers, which has taken me a lot of time. and I know a method that can change the smallest width by setting the value of density, but this cannot make the smallest width reach the 654 I want because according to the calculation formula, it cannot be completely divided

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

adb shell 
wm size 1920x1280 

this?

By changing size and density, it may be possible to change the smallest width.
according to the formula : smallest width(dp) = min(size.width, size.height)/(density(dpi)/160) ,
but I am looking for a way to directly modify the smallest width from the Android system source code.
